# How to change default file save location for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a little function below that checks if a file exists and if not creates a new one.

```
public static void LogFile(string sEventName)
{
    StreamWriter log;
    if (!File.Exists("NETSlogfile.txt"))
    {
        log = new StreamWriter("NETSlogfile.txt");
    }
    else
    {
        log = File.AppendText("NETSlogfile.txt");
    }
    log.WriteLine("Data Time: " + DateTime.Now + " Event: " + sEventName);
    // Console.WriteLine(sEventName); // write responses to console for debugging
    log.Close();
}
```

Now I currently get an exception:

> "Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\NETSlogfile.txt' is denied."

Which I care little for, as I don't really want the file saving in this location and can just type in any file path, however, I was wondering if there was a way to set this default file path from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\' to somewhere else?

Specifically the line 'log = new StreamWriter("NETSlogfile.txt");' creates a new file (or at least tries to) at this default file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\', is there anyway to change that default file path?

Comment: Specify the full path in the parameter maybe?

Comment: I know I can do that, I'm just curious if you can change the default file path.

Comment: I think with any program, the default save location if you don't specify the path would be the location of the executable.

Comment: God I sounded arrogant haha... Probably still do

Answer (score 1):

You do not have permissions to write to the IIS directory any files but you can write files within your application root directory or any sub directory in it

what you can do is create a folder in your application and then use it's path to write and read text file which would be like:

```
var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/NETSlogfile.txt");
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
```

and now use the filePath variable which contains the full path of it.

Assuming you have a Temp named folder in your application directory.

Comment: This is a helpful alternative, but I'm asking if I can change the directory this would save to (the IIS directory) to somewhere else.

Comment: you will need to explicitly specify the full path i think for that.

Comment: Ok, so the default file path of the IIS directory can't be changed? The only alternative would be to specifiy the full file location?

Comment: normally when we don't specify any path it would write what ever the location is from where the application is running.